# function __autoload & using require_once / ignore certain instances

Tags: php, function, autoload, instanceof

I am using the autoload function for a certain library... But I am trying to implement Doctrine and I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error.

I believe its because I am creating = new instance and in the autoload... It checks a different directory.

Is there a way to create new instances of classes that will ignore the autoload function? Or should I move all doctrine files in the directory that my autoload function checks... Ideally I would not want to do this to keep a structure of libraries within my project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a 500 error, you might want to check your logs first. Depending on your site setup (`apachectl -S` to find your site configuration file), check your logs (`tail -n500 /path/to/logs`)

If I were to guess, I'd say the issue is memory here. The logs will tell though.

Have you created your own __autoload function? If so, could you post it here? I suspect that's the issue (memory leak).